# A monkey pulley problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

[image: The height of monkey from ground is 10m]

I am having trouble understanding the physics underlying the situation mentioned below. A clear account on the situation may help me understand the physics underlying this particular problem.

A monkey of mass 4 kg is hanging on a light rope passing over a pulley as shown. Block is placed on support and monkey and block are on same level initially.
If M=4kg (mass of block) then what would be the time taken by monkey to climb up to the pulley (10m) , if its acceleration with respect to rope is 2 m/s^2.

I think i am not able to comprehend this problem completely as to what is happening.
What I have been attempting to do is that the monkey cannot accelerate upward until he applies a downward force more than 40N downward on the rope which is another way of saying developing a tension greater than 40N on the rope , but then i think that the rope would have to get slack as the monkey cannot climb until a force of 40N is upward but then he disturbs the block as well.
It would be highly appreciated if someone gives the correct account of what is actually happening.

[For verification purposes, the answer is 2.5*( 2 )^1/2 seconds or 2.5 times square root of 2 seconds